# getting error " failed to obtain node locks, tried " when starting second node in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am just a beginner in learning elastic search and started to setup 2 node cluster on windows 10 box.

I have configured the two nodes based on the forums and articles.

However, I am able to start the first node but when starting the second node, it throws an error.

```
[2018-11-05T16:07:31,935][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [elastic_search_node_02] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[C:\Elastic_search_cluster\data\elastic_search_cluster]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?
```

The following is the setup for both the nodes,

Node 1 dir

```
C:\Elastic_search_cluster\elasticsearch-6.4.2_node01\
```

Node 2 dir

```
C:\Elastic_search_cluster\elasticsearch-6.4.2_node02\
```

Data folder

C:\Elastic_search_cluster\data\

Logs folder

C:\Elastic_search_cluster\logs\

Node 1 configuration

```
cluster.name: elastic_search_cluster
node.name: elastic_search_node_01
node.master: true
node.data: true
path.data: C:\Elastic_search_cluster\data\
path.logs: C:\Elastic_search_cluster\logs\
network.host: localhost
http.port: 9200
```

Node 2 configuration

```
cluster.name: elastic_search_cluster
node.name: elastic_search_node_02
node.master: false
node.data: true
path.data: C:\Elastic_search_cluster\data\
path.logs: C:\Elastic_search_cluster\logs\
network.host: localhost
http.port: 9201
```

Please advise on the configuration or any other recommendation. Does the data and logs folder path need to be separate for each node.

Do i need to set other parameters like the below ?

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts:
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure node.max_local_storage_nodes param is set to # of nodes in cluster locally ( In your case 2 ) . I notice that you already have node names different.

in yaml ,

```
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 2
```

Comment: When i make path.data to different paths, it works fine. Does it mean that data folder should be different for both the nodes ?

Comment: not required if you specify number of max_local_storage_nodes

Comment: in which node, i need to set the configuration node.max_local_storage_nodes: 2

Comment: I set the configuration in the both the nodes and it worked fine. Many thanks Nirmal

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to go to docker on "elastic-search" and tab "exec" and then navigated to "share/elast../data", but it only have permission root, because this folder was created by root, and the user "elastic" not have permision to write, so I run this command "chmod -R 777 data", I think its a fast solution but in production mode maybe it will get some problems.
You can see more [enter link description here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/96601)
Sorry by my english

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).